# WPF DataGrid Cell binding by data from Parent control

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I am trying to sort this out and cannot see light in the dark.

I have worksheets (tables) in workspace. All dynamic (columns, mount of tables, ...). Based on object for worksheet I would like to set datagrid rotation.

VM structure:

```
ControlVM : 
{ Workspace: [ 
  {  
  Worksheet: [
    {     
      DataViewBindingData: [DataView type],    
      isRotated: rue | false    
    },
    {...} 
  ]
}


<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" >
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Workspace}" >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Expander Header="{Binding Path=WorksheetName}" ExpandDirection="Down" IsExpanded="True" >
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <DataGrid CanUserResizeColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" CanUserSortColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" CanUserAddRows="False" Margin="5" 
                                                  SelectionUnit="Cell" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataViewBindingData}" Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded" 
                                                  BeginningEdit="DataGrid_BeginningEdit" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Expander>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

And inside custom styles resources in my base style for control (header, cells), I am trying to access isRotated property of worksheet object

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridBase" TargetType="Control">
     <Style.Triggers>
         <!--  TODO cannot find an ancestor for data binding -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsRotated, Converter={StaticResource DebugConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"  Value="True">
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1" ScaleY="1" />
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style >

<!--DataGrid Cells-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridBase}" />
```

And thats the problem, I dont know how to access parent control's data to bind the property. Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implicit `DataContext` inside `DataGridCell` is actually the current DataGridRow's bound item. So in this case you have to use `RelativeSource` to find the `DataGrid` and set `Path` to `DataContext.IsRotated` (the `DataGrid`'s DataContext is a `Worksheet`):

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsRotated, 
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}
                       Converter={StaticResource DebugConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
              Value="True">
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: Thanks for response! I came up with similar solution, but problem where I got stuck is that DataGrid is using property named as DataViewBindingData and on the same level (property) is the isRotated. So how u can access this one from ItemSource of datagrid?

Workspace --[has many]--> Worksheet { DataViewBindingData, IsRotated }, and ItemSource for DataGrid is DataViewBindingData.
 
In code: ObservableCollection<Worksheet> Workspace. 

Thanks for your help, appreciate it

Comment: @stenly have you actually tried this code? I know the `ItemsSource` is bound to `DataViewBindingData`, from that the DataGrid's DataContext should be a `Worksheet`, and a `Worksheet` has the property `IsRotated`. So the code I posted in my answer will help bind the `IsRotated` and check against the value `True` in DataTrigger.

Comment: it works :) but how is that possible? Thanks for help

Comment: @stenly it's how Binding works. Here the `RelativeSource` will instruct the Binding to find the source upwards in the visual tree, we set `AncestorType=DataGrid`, so it will find the first DataGrid and use it as the `Source`. The `Path` is set to `DataContext.IsRotated` meaning that we first access to `DataContext` (which is a `Worksheet`) then next to `IsRotated`. So we reach the destination, the Binding has all info to run smoothly.